# Fibrant objects in $\mathbb{S}$-local model structure on $Top_*$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, model-categories, homology, bousfield-localization

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be the sphere spectrum. We can localize the category of based spaces, $Top_*$ at a homology theory, and hence at $\mathbb{S}$.

Equipping $Top_*$ with the Quillen model structure (weak homotopy equivalences, and Serre fibrations), and Bousfield localizing at $\mathbb{S}$ gives a model structure with the weak equivalences the isomorphisms on stable homotopy groups, i.e. $\pi_*^\mathrm{st}$-isomorphisms.

Is there a good characterization of the fibrant ($\mathbb{S}$-local) objects in this model structure?

In particular, are "nice" spaces fibrant in this model structure, e.g. nilpotent spaces, simply connected spaces, etc?

Comment: Isn't this the same as localizing at $H\mathbb{Z}$? Anyway: It looks like Eilenberg-MacLane spaces for abelian groups are local (since cohomology is a stable invariant), and local objects are closed under homotopy limits, so every nilpotent space is local. Since this is the same as HZ-localization, you can probably find lots more information in Bousfield's original paper inventing "Bousfield localization" for spaces ;)

Comment: @DylanWilson I believe this is precisely the same thing. Do you have a reference for this fact? I’ve tried showing it but got nowhere quick

Comment: Elaborating on Dylan's comment: the $\mathbb{S}$-local model structure is actually the same as the $H\mathbb{Z}$-local one, since homology detects equivalences between bounded below spectra. $H\mathbb{Z}$-local spaces are called semi-$\mathbb{Z}$-complete in Bousfield and Kan (VII 2.2), but not much is said about them. Any $\mathbb{Z}$-complete space is $H\mathbb{Z}$-local, since by definition it is a homotopy limit of spaces of the form $\Omega^\infty(H\mathbb{Z}\wedge X)$. Any nilpotent space is $\mathbb{Z}$-complete, hence $H\mathbb{Z}$-local.

Comment: I suppose one way to show this is to show that an isomorphism on stable homotopy groups is an isomorphism on integral homology? Then both localized model structures are the same.

Comment: @User1236262625 yes, this is true (for bounded below spectra), as Marc said- it's the Hurewicz theorem.